# Using REPLACE() Function Within a CONTAINS Predicate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm wondering if there's any way to use `REPLACE()` within a `CONTAINS` predicate.

For example, I know if I use:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONTAINS(column, 'searchWord')
```

It works with no problems; however, if I use:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONTAINS(REPLACE(column, 'oldPhrase', 'newPhrase'), 'searchWord')
```

It will give me an error because it is expecting a column instead of a string. If there's no way to do this, what's the best alternative?

Comment: Hmmm . . . You could create a computed column and index that.

Comment: Do you need full-text searching, or would a `LIKE` clause fulfill your needs? That would work without additional modifications to schema, but it's functionally quite different, so it might be irrelevant. Just a thought.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen I have my query set up so it either uses full-text search, or the LIKE clause. If I could just write a query that uses both REPLACE and full-text search, that would solve most of my problems.

Comment: @GordonLinoff would I be able to full-text index a computed column?

Comment: @bkhosh2 . . . I wasn't sure (which is why I answered as a comment).  But yes, you can if the column is persisted.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with a CTE ?

```
WITH r AS (
    SELECT column0, column1, column2,
           REPLACE(column, 'oldPhrase', 'newPhrase') col
      FROM table
)
SELECT * 
    FROM r 
    WHERE CONTAINS(col, 'searchWord');
```

Comment: I tried using this, however I get an error. I need to be able to full-text index the 'newly created columns' within the WITH clause.